# find by conditions with 'members'

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have 3 model:
Association HasMany Service
Service HasBelongs Association and HasMany Member
Member HasBelongs Service

I want find member by association but I find Service by association.

```
$associations = $this->Member->Service->Association->find('all',
                                                                 array(
                                                                'fields'=>array('id','libelle')
                                                                     ));
```

the result debug is:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Association' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'libelle' => 'الادارة العامة للصحة العسكرية'
        ),
        'Service' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'libelle' => 'Divers',
                'association_id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'association_id' => '1'
            ),
            (int) 2 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'libelle' => 'مكتب الضبط   BO',
                'association_id' => '1'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Association' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'libelle' => 'أعضاء الديوان والمديرين'
        ),
        'Service' => array()
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Association' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'libelle' => 'المستشفات والمراكز والمصحات '
        ),
        'Service' => array()
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Association' => array(
            'id' => '4',
            'libelle' => 'المستشفى العسكري الاصلي للتعليم '
        ),
        'Service' => array()
    )
```

I want find the member by association example: all member that belong to the Association الادارة العامة للصحة العسكرية ie all members of the services 1, 2, 3

Comment: try to use condition in your query .

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'contain' to do that.
There are some examples in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html